# How to make WCF work reliable?

Tags: c#, wcf, hosting

I have some questions on how to make my WCF service reliable.

Setup
My services contains 3 WCF services, 2 is a regular Webservice over HTTP and another is a TCP service using Protobuf. The TCP service is customized in many ways to make it working as good as possible with the Winform clikent.

This is then hosted in a Windows Service.

The WCF project contains a CustomHostServiceFactory where ApplyConfiguration is used to load all all cache data(all services uses the same BLL where the cache is).

```
protected override void ApplyConfiguration()
        {
            base.ApplyConfiguration();

            Startup();
        }
```

The Windows Services contains the following on startup

```
private ServiceHost StartService(Type serviceType)
        {
            ServiceHost serviceHost = null;

            // Create a ServiceHost for the CalculatorService type and 
            // provide the base address.
            Console.WriteLine("Creating service " + serviceType.FullName);
            serviceHost = new ServiceHost(serviceType);

            serviceHost.Opened += serviceHost_Opened;
            serviceHost.Closed += serviceHost_Closed;

            // Open the ServiceHostBase to create listeners and start 
            // listening for messages.
            Console.WriteLine("Starting service...");
            serviceHost.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Service started successfully");
            Console.WriteLine("...");
            return serviceHost;

        }
```

This code used used both from the Main(ServiceBase) and from the OnStart(override) in Windows service.

Problem
Now I have to make sure that this is the correct why to set this up? Can a service receive a call during startup but before the init of the caches have been runned?

Comment: why not registering faulted event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I have to make sure that this is the correct why to set this up? Can a service receive a call during startup but before the init of the caches have been runned?

Just make sure that the init code runs before `serviceHost.Open();`.

If a client calls a service before endpoint is available, the client will get a connection exception. When endpoint is open you can be sure that the init code has been called prior to the `Open()` and that your service is ready to serve the requests.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the service only accepts requests after `.Open()` is called. You will get `EndpointNotFoundException`s occurring if it isn't open yet.

Also, the startup code for the service itself - i.e. the public ctor() isn't run until the first request comes through.